# get_results() doesn't fetch the result

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch `offer_price` from my Database table but it is not showing any error, just shows a blank screen.

```
if ( $make=="1" && $model=="MDX" && $year>="2001" && $year<="2004" ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT `offer_price` FROM wp_cost_estimation WHERE make='Acura' AND model_name='MDX' AND year_from>='2001' AND year_to<='2004'");

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result->offer_price;
    }  

} else{
    echo "try something else";
}
```

my desire result is `offer_price=300`

Comment: And that SQL runs fine from MySQL Workbench or something similar and returns 1+ rows of results? Can you try echoing out $results, e.g. with print_r ? It might be worth adding an echo for the case that $results contains no rows too.

Comment: i have run my query in phpmyadmin it gives desire result

Comment: Where is this code running, what does your PHP error log say, and where do those variables come from in the if check? Keep in mind everybody here is unpaid, and a volunteer, if your issue is time sensitive you may not get an answer in time

Comment: if ( $make=="1" && $model=="MDX" && $year>="2001" && $year<="2004" ) { echo 'OK' } // does your code pass all those conditions to get to the query?